# Test whether an expression contains a particular pattern

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, built-in-symbols

How to test whether an expression contains a particular pattern ?

I made a function for myself that tests whether an expression contains `Plus` or not.

```
f[X_] := (FirstCase[{X}, HoldPattern@Plus[__], False, Infinity] =!= False)
```

So,

```
Clear[x,y,z]

f[x*y+z]
True

f[x^y]
False
```

It worked correctly for two simple examples.

Q1) I am not sure about the reliability of my function. What do you think about `f` ?

Q2) Is there a more intuitive, simple method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit more direct:

```
ContainsPlus = Not@*FreeQ[Plus]
```

Examples:

```
ContainsPlus[x * y + z]
(* True *)

ContainsPlus[x^y]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Nice! The `Composition` (`@*`) might not seem intuitive, in the sense that in my mind you have defined an operator rather than a function. The `Composition` makes it apply to what comes next. The function equivalent would be `hasPlus[expr_] := Not@FreeQ[expr, Plus]`. This is not as sparse, hence inferior.